# How to compare two lists and extract position, index and neighbors?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, hpc

Let's assume we have two lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

That's the basic structure:

```
     Columns
Rows    0      1      2      3      4
0       1      2      3      4      5
1       6      7      8      9      10
```

Each of the elements should print a line with a bit of metadata (index, position and neighbors):

```
row/col   Print statement
0/0       "Row index=0, Column Index=0, Value=1, Value below=6, Value to the right = 2"
0/1       "Row index=0, Column Index=1, Value=2, Value below=7, Value to the right = 3"
0/2       "Row index=0, Column Index=2, Value=3, Value below=8, Value to the right = 4"
0/3       "Row index=0, Column Index=3, Value=4, Value below=9, Value to the right = 5"
0/4       "Row index=0, Column Index=4, Value=5, Value below=10, Value to the right = NaN"
1/0       "Row index=1, Column Index=0, Value=6, Value below=NaN, Value to the right = 7"
1/1       "Row index=1, Column Index=1, Value=7, Value below=NaN, Value to the right = 8"
1/2       "Row index=1, Column Index=2, Value=8, Value below=NaN, Value to the right = 9"
1/3       "Row index=1, Column Index=3, Value=9, Value below=NaN, Value to the right = 10"
1/4       "Row index=1, Column Index=4, Value=10, Value below=NaN, Value to the right = NaN"
```

Is there something like list comprehension or any other way to compare these two lists as quickly as possible?

I wouldn't want to use for/while loops as they are considered to be very slow.

EDIT: The solution will be the core of a big data function that has to handle millions of comparisons. Using traditional for loops would extremely slow down my function. That's why I am looking for a faster way to do this.

Comment: `for` loops would be the way to solve this.

Comment: *"I wouldn't want to use for/while loops as they are considered to be very slow."* So the problem here is that you think basic language constructs like `for` and `while` are unsuitable for solving such problems, when in fact they are completely suitable. So write this using `for` loops. The slowest thing your code will be doing is `print`.

Comment: It's also just unclear what you mean by compare? What are you trying to do and why would a `for` loop be unsuitable or a list comprehension suitable i.e. what list of compared values are you trying to generate?

Comment: @Daniel try my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: Have you considered using a module like pandas? Or do you want the solution to be  python's builtin only?

Comment: Pandas is not designed for handling huge datasets but it could be easily replaced by CuDF, a pandas like dataframe API of NVIDIA Rapids to perform operations on a GPU. I guess Python's builtin functions offer more possibilities to speed up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of strings, then you have to iterate - over each element.  String formatting like that works with scalar elements, not whole arrays.

It is possible to generate the values using whole array operations.  But the result will be some form of array, not your list of strings.

For example:

```
In [198]: list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
     ...: list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]                                                             
In [199]: arr = np.array([list1,list2])                                                        
In [200]: arr                                                                                  
Out[200]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

An easy way to iterate on the array, while also displaying the indices is:

```
In [201]: list(np.ndenumerate(arr))                                                            
Out[201]: 
[((0, 0), 1),
 ((0, 1), 2),
 ((0, 2), 3),
 ((0, 3), 4),
 ((0, 4), 5),
 ((1, 0), 6),
 ((1, 1), 7),
 ((1, 2), 8),
 ((1, 3), 9),
 ((1, 4), 10)]
```

This is still an iteration.  We can get the indices in array form with:

```
In [215]: np.indices(arr.shape)                                                                
Out[215]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
In [216]: I,J = np.indices(arr.shape)
```

And stacking those indices with a values:

```
In [218]: np.stack((I.ravel(),J.ravel(),arr.ravel()),axis=1)                                   
Out[218]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 0,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  0,  6],
       [ 1,  1,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  8],
       [ 1,  3,  9],
       [ 1,  4, 10]])
```

To get the below and right values we can generate a padded array:

```
In [223]: arr1 = np.pad(arr.astype(float),[(0,1),(0,1)],mode='constant',constant_values=np.nan)
     ...:                                                                                      
In [224]: arr1                                                                                 
Out[224]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5., nan],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

Note that I had to convert the array to float to accept the float `np.nan` value.

And combining everything:

```
In [225]: np.stack((I.ravel(),J.ravel(),arr.ravel(),arr1[1:,:-1].ravel(),arr1[:-1,1:].ravel()),
     ...: axis=1)                                                                              
Out[225]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  6.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  7.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  8.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  4.,  9.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  5., 10., nan],
       [ 1.,  0.,  6., nan,  7.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  7., nan,  8.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  8., nan,  9.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  9., nan, 10.],
       [ 1.,  4., 10., nan, nan]])
```

To get your list of strings, we can define a format string:

```
In [230]: astr = "Row index={}, Column index={}, Value={}, Value below={}, Value to the right={}"
```

and apply it to reach row (yes, this does iterate)

```
In [233]: for row in Out[225]: 
     ...:     print(astr.format(*row)) 
     ...:                                                                                      
Row index=0.0, Column index=0.0, Value=1.0, Value below=6.0, Value to the right=2.0
Row index=0.0, Column index=1.0, Value=2.0, Value below=7.0, Value to the right=3.0
Row index=0.0, Column index=2.0, Value=3.0, Value below=8.0, Value to the right=4.0
Row index=0.0, Column index=3.0, Value=4.0, Value below=9.0, Value to the right=5.0
Row index=0.0, Column index=4.0, Value=5.0, Value below=10.0, Value to the right=nan
Row index=1.0, Column index=0.0, Value=6.0, Value below=nan, Value to the right=7.0
Row index=1.0, Column index=1.0, Value=7.0, Value below=nan, Value to the right=8.0
Row index=1.0, Column index=2.0, Value=8.0, Value below=nan, Value to the right=9.0
Row index=1.0, Column index=3.0, Value=9.0, Value below=nan, Value to the right=10.0
Row index=1.0, Column index=4.0, Value=10.0, Value below=nan, Value to the right=nan
```

If we omit all those `ravel`, we get a 3d array of values:

```
In [234]: np.stack((I,J,arr,arr1[1:,:-1],arr1[:-1,1:]),axis=2)                                 
Out[234]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  6.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  7.,  3.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  8.,  4.],
        [ 0.,  3.,  4.,  9.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  4.,  5., 10., nan]],

       [[ 1.,  0.,  6., nan,  7.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  7., nan,  8.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  8., nan,  9.],
        [ 1.,  3.,  9., nan, 10.],
        [ 1.,  4., 10., nan, nan]]])
 In [235]: _.reshape(-1,5)           # to get the 2d array  
 ...
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer to avoid traditional for loops. Regarding your code snippet: ```for row in Out[225]:```: Probably you mean ```for row in result_array:```. ```result_array``` is the array you stacked/combined one step before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach your problem is to use for-loops. The code below accepts multiple rows and store it in a dictionary.

```
row1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
row2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
row3 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
row4 = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
row5 = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

def create_array_dict(*args):
    return {row_index: {column_index: value for column_index, value in enumerate(row_list)} for row_index, row_list in enumerate(args)}

arr = create_array_dict(row1, row2, row3, row4, row5)
```

And after creating the dictionary, we can printout the results:

```
def print_output(arr):
    for row, value in arr.items():
        for column, value in value.items():
            try:
                print(f"Row index={row}, Column Index={column}, Value={value},Value below={arr[row + 1][column]}, Value to the right={arr[row][column + 1]}")
            except:
                try:
                    print(f"Row index={row}, Column Index={column}, Value={value},Value below={arr[row + 1][column]}, Value to the right=None")
                except:
                    try:
                        print(f"Row index={row}, Column Index={column}, Value={value},Value below=None, Value to the right={arr[row][column + 1]}")
                    except:
                        print(f"Row index={row}, Column Index={column}, Value={value},Value below=None, Value to the right=None")
```

Ouput:

```
Row index=0, Column Index=0, Value=1,Value below=6, Value to the right=2
Row index=0, Column Index=1, Value=2,Value below=7, Value to the right=3
Row index=0, Column Index=2, Value=3,Value below=8, Value to the right=4
Row index=0, Column Index=3, Value=4,Value below=9, Value to the right=5
Row index=0, Column Index=4, Value=5,Value below=10, Value to the right=None
Row index=1, Column Index=0, Value=6,Value below=11, Value to the right=7
Row index=1, Column Index=1, Value=7,Value below=12, Value to the right=8
Row index=1, Column Index=2, Value=8,Value below=13, Value to the right=9
Row index=1, Column Index=3, Value=9,Value below=14, Value to the right=10
Row index=1, Column Index=4, Value=10,Value below=15, Value to the right=None
Row index=2, Column Index=0, Value=11,Value below=16, Value to the right=12
Row index=2, Column Index=1, Value=12,Value below=17, Value to the right=13
Row index=2, Column Index=2, Value=13,Value below=18, Value to the right=14
Row index=2, Column Index=3, Value=14,Value below=19, Value to the right=15
Row index=2, Column Index=4, Value=15,Value below=20, Value to the right=None
Row index=3, Column Index=0, Value=16,Value below=21, Value to the right=17
Row index=3, Column Index=1, Value=17,Value below=22, Value to the right=18
Row index=3, Column Index=2, Value=18,Value below=23, Value to the right=19
Row index=3, Column Index=3, Value=19,Value below=24, Value to the right=20
Row index=3, Column Index=4, Value=20,Value below=25, Value to the right=None
Row index=4, Column Index=0, Value=21,Value below=None, Value to the right=22
Row index=4, Column Index=1, Value=22,Value below=None, Value to the right=23
Row index=4, Column Index=2, Value=23,Value below=None, Value to the right=24
Row index=4, Column Index=3, Value=24,Value below=None, Value to the right=25
Row index=4, Column Index=4, Value=25,Value below=None, Value to the right=None
```

Comment: You're missing the case when you're in the last column, but there's still value below. E.g. for row=0, column=4 value below is 10, not None.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed my answer to pass the case